# Issue including library C++

Tags: c++, g++, static-libraries, unix-ar

I have a very simple C++ file `Multiplier.cpp` with the corresponding header file, from which I have created a library using the following commands

```
$ g++ -o Multiplier.o -c Multiplier.cpp
$ ar cr libMultiplier.a Multiplier.o
```

In a new directory, I have created a `Calculator.cpp` (with corresponding header file) which uses the `Multiplier` class. the header file `Calculator.h` has the corresponding `#include "Multiplier.h"

The header file `Calculator.h` has the corresponding `#include "Multiplier.h"`

I copied the created library into this directory I tried to compile `Calculator.cpp` using the following command:

```
$ g++ -o Calculator Calculator.cpp -L. -lMultiplier
```

which gives me these errors:

```
In file included from Calculator.cpp:1:
Calculator.h:1:24: error: Multiplier.h: No such file or directory
In file included from Calculator.cpp:1:
Calculator.h:6: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Multiplier’ with no type
Calculator.h:6: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘&’ token
Calculator.h:8: error: expected `)' before ‘&’ token
Calculator.cpp:5: error: redefinition of ‘class something::Calculator’
Calculator.h:5: error: previous definition of ‘class something::Calculator’`
```

I have searched for a long time but can't work out what is happening.
I am using GCC 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your include file `Multiplier.h` is in another folder. How do you expect the compiler to find it? You need to tell the compiler where the file is, either using the `-I` command line flag and supplying the path of the include file, or using a path in the `#include` directive.

Comment: Does the library not have the `Multiplier.h` file in it?

Comment: @luketorjussen No, that’s not how libraries work. The compiler doesn’t even see the library – that’s the job of the linker (those are two fundamentally separate components even though you invoke them here through the same executable).

Comment: so when you create a library, you still need to copy in all the header files too?

Comment: The header files are used by the compiler for the definition, and the library is used by the linker to get the implementation?

Comment: @luketorjussen The header files are used by the compiler for the *declaration*, the library is used by the linker for the *definition* (= implementation).